# ORA-00998: Вы должны присвоить имя этому выражению, задав псевдоним столбца

Tags: sql, oracle

при попытке создать представление, получаю ошибку сабжа.

сам запрос:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_OPT
AS SELECT TRUNC(Date_Utils.Ctime2date(Mo.Date_To_Ship)),
    Mo.Customer,
    Mo.Estimated_Weight,
    Mo.Estimated_Volume
  FROM Mc_Orders Mo
  WHERE not Mo.status='C' 
  and mo.date_to_ship BETWEEN (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate-3))) AND (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate+3)))
    /*  WHERE mo.type_id='A';*/;
```

Comment: Задайте псевдоним для 1 столбца: `TRUNC(Date_Utils.Ctime2date(Mo.Date_To_Ship)) as SomeName` к примеру.

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Задайте псевдоним для 1 столбца:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_OPT
AS SELECT TRUNC(Date_Utils.Ctime2date(Mo.Date_To_Ship)) as SomeName,
  Mo.Customer,
  Mo.Estimated_Weight,
  Mo.Estimated_Volume
FROM Mc_Orders Mo
WHERE not Mo.status='C' 
  and mo.date_to_ship BETWEEN (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate-3))) AND 
  (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate+3)))
  /*  WHERE mo.type_id='A';*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще один способ задать псевдонимы столбцам - перечислить их после названия view в скобках:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_OPT (Some_column, customer, estimated_weight, estimated_volume)
AS SELECT TRUNC(Date_Utils.Ctime2date(Mo.Date_To_Ship)),
    Mo.Customer,
    Mo.Estimated_Weight,
    Mo.Estimated_Volume
  FROM Mc_Orders Mo
  WHERE not Mo.status='C' 
  and mo.date_to_ship BETWEEN (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate-3))) AND (Date_Utils.Date2ctime(TRUNC(sysdate+3)))
    /*  WHERE mo.type_id='A';*/;
```